# ConcurrentModificationException When using iterator loop

Tags: java

I'm using an iterator but I still seem to get the modification exception when calling 
`iterator.next()`

```
public void render(Graphics g) {
    if(consoleShown) {

        int boxHeight = 0;

        Iterator<String> iterator = output.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            boxHeight += ((int)writefont.getStringBounds(iterator.next(), frc).getHeight());
        }

        if(boxHeight > 225) {
            boxHeight = 225;
        }

        for(int i = offset; i < offset + 25; i++) { //Offset being the line from the list being displayed.
            if(i < output.size()) {
                //Inverse the range to reverse the order of the list being displayed.
                //The irriterator adds the new value to the beginning of the list and not the end to avoid exceptions.
                g.drawString(output.get((int)(Utils.inverseRange(i, output.size())) - 1), 10, (i - offset + 1) * (int)writefont.getStringBounds(output.get(i), frc).getHeight());
            }
        }

        g.drawLine(0, boxHeight + 3, game.getWidth(), boxHeight + 3);
        g.drawString(input, 10, boxHeight + 12);
    }
}
```

My assumption is that I'm accessing the list using `output.get(i)` further down but I don't think there's a possible way I could add an iterator in that scenario.

Basically I have a list of strings, each string has the font height measured and added to an integer.

Comment: That code will not cause the error (unless there is a threading issue). For given exception to be thrown the collection being iterated has to be modified, but this cannot happen in the given example (unless there is a threading issue).

Comment: Also 1) if threads are being used, say so; and 2) an enhanced for-loop *uses* an Iterator and `hasNext`/`next` internally so switching it out with a manual invocation of such will never solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the modification exception is related to the iterator?  There is a lot going on in that line, there are several other possible things that could be going wrong, not related to your iterator.

I would recommend breaking that line up into several lines of code and assigning the results of iterator.next() to a variable.

Comment: Not really. The exception is to do with some form of collection and the list 'output' is the only one in the class.

Comment: Oh!  I think I might know what's going on here.  Multiple concurrent calls to render().

You probably need to rethink the concurrency of this method.  And maybe you don't need to recalculate that entire height every time you draw?  That's kind of expensive.  Perhaps you can recalculate the height each time something gets added to the output list, as part of a setter/adder method.  Then of course save that value as an instance variable and use it for each render.

Comment: Thanks, I took your advice and only did the calculation when the value changes then I also took to using CopyOnWriteArrayList instead of an ArrayList. The double list isn't really an issue as the object is only used for storing a history of debugging commands.